# Java Web Service MYSQL with parameter

Tags: java, mysql, json

i'm new to web services, I had implement a web services and all work fine with my MYSQL, but now for use that web services with my android app I need to add a parameter in the http request, this is my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList; 

public class getDonationList {  


public ArrayList<myDonations> getList(Connection con) throws SQLException 
{
    ArrayList<myDonations> donationList = new ArrayList<myDonations>();
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM donations WHERE email = "+ variable);

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        //System.out.println(rs);
        try
        {
            while(rs.next())
            {
                myDonations myDonationsObj = new myDonations();
                myDonationsObj.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                myDonationsObj.setOnlus(rs.getString("text1"));
                myDonationsObj.setData(rs.getString("text2"));
                myDonationsObj.setImporto(rs.getInt("coin"));
                donationList.add(myDonationsObj);
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return donationList;     
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

import com.google.gson.Gson;


@Path("/donationService")
public class DonationService
{
    @GET
    @Path("/donation")
    @Produces("application/json")

    public String donations(@QueryParam("email") String email)
    {
        String donations = null;
        ArrayList<myDonations> donationList = new ArrayList<myDonations>();
        try
        {
            donationList = new DonationManager().getList();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            donations = gson.toJson(donationList);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return donations;
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import connessionedb.Database;

public class DonationManager
{
    public ArrayList<myDonations> getList() throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList<myDonations> courseList = new ArrayList<myDonations>();
        Database db = new Database();
        Connection con = db.getConnection();
        getDonationList list = new getDonationList();
        courseList = list.getList(con);
        return courseList;
    }
}
```

---

I need the service accept the parameter "variable" like this:
http://localhost:8440/MyProject/donationService/donation?email=variable
becouse then in my andorid app I take the variable from TextView.

Someone can help me to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the email received over the service as part of your query to the database.

You could change:

```
public ArrayList<myDonations> getList() throws Exception
```

to be:

```
public ArrayList<myDonations> getList(String email) throws Exception
```

Change:

```
donationList = new DonationManager().getList();
```

to be:

```
donationList = new DonationManager().getList(email);
```

Change:

```
public ArrayList<myDonations> getList(Connection con) throws SQLException
```

to be:

```
public ArrayList<myDonations> getList(Connection con, String email) throws SQLException
```

If you apply this pattern then you can get the string value from your service down to your SQL.

Also, you should investigate using parameter markers in your prepared statement to avoid sql injection.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how pass @QueryParam from DonationService Class to getDonationList Class and use that in my query selection....

Comment: added some hopefully sample changes you might apply

Comment: Thanks for your help Mike, I have only one problem now, in class DonationManager I have an error in courseList = list.getList(con); It's correct i I cange that in courseList = list.getList(con, email);?

Ok isn't correct, now I haven't connection to DB....

Comment: Solved! Thanks Mike for your help! I follow your suggestion and I fix my code like that:
'code
public ArrayList<myDonations> getList(Connection con, String checkemail) throws SQLException
{ 
 ArrayList<myDonations> donationList = new ArrayList<myDonations>(); 
 PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM donations where email = ?");
 stmt.setString(1, checkemail);
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
<code>

Comment: Great, really glad you got it. Also glad to see you've changed to use parameter markers. Important to protect against SQL injection but also useful for performance.

Comment: Yes only thanks for you, sorry i'm looking how to format code comment -.-'