# Android Parsing JsonArray to hashmap from java WS

Tags: android, arrays, json, web-services, hashmap

I'm trying to get jsonarray from http request and I am following this tutorial:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

I have a doubt, in the tutorial the json file is this:

```
{
    "contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c2012",
                "name": "Eminem",
                "email": "eminem@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is my json:

```
[
{"email":"prova","one":"test","data":"2015-02-10 00:00:00.0","cash":100},
{"email":"prova","one":"provadue","data":"2015-02-11 23:41:32.0","cash":15}
]
```

and this is my "contact" class on web service:

```
public class contacts
{
private String email;
private String one;
private String data;
private int cash;

public contacts()
{

}

public contacts(String email, String one, String data, int cash)
{
super();
this.email = email;
this.one = one;
this.data = data;;
this.cash = cash;
}


public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getOne() {
    return one;
}

public void setOne(String one) {
    this.one = one;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public int getCash() {
    return cash;
}

public void setCash(int cash) {
    this.cash = cash;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
return "Contact [email=" + email + ", one=" + one + ", data=" + data + ", cash=" + cash + "]";
}

}
```

Now following the tutorial there is that part:

```
// Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
```

I thought that this refers to:

```
{
    "contacts": [
```

but in my Json I haven't that Node, what can I do to change the tutorial script or change my json response from web service?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this line:

```
contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(0);
```

But, you should always add a key to the JSON String (like that "contacts" key in the tutorial example) and use:

```
contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");
```

to have your JSON Array.

EDIT: Ok, so I created an example of how to get the key for your array using your `contacts` class. I couldn't implement WebService you put in the example but this should give you the idea of what to do to get your key...

Your `contacts` class is intact.

I created a new class called `ContactsObject`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ContactsObject {

    private ArrayList<contacts> contacts;   // THIS IS HOW YOUR KEY WILL BE NAMED (in this case, "contacts")

    public void setListContacts(ArrayList<contacts> contacts)
    {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    public ArrayList<contacts> getListContacts()
    {
        return this.contacts;
    }
}
```

Then in `MainActivity`, (in `onCreate`, but that is not that important) I added these lines of code to test everything:

```
        ContactsObject objj = new ContactsObject();

        ArrayList<contacts> moreContacts = new ArrayList<contacts>();

        contacts cnt = new contacts();
        cnt.setCash(100);
        cnt.setData("some data");
        cnt.setEmail("some mail");
        cnt.setOne("one?");
        moreContacts.add(cnt);

        contacts cnt1 = new contacts();
        cnt1.setCash(100);
        cnt1.setData("some data1");
        cnt1.setEmail("some mail1");
        cnt1.setOne("2?");
        moreContacts.add(cnt1);

        contacts cnt2 = new contacts();
        cnt2.setCash(100);
        cnt2.setData("some data2");
        cnt2.setEmail("some mail2");
        cnt2.setOne("3?");
        moreContacts.add(cnt2);  
        // "moreContacts" is similar to that example's "donationList", I think...

        objj.setListContacts(moreContacts);  // doing this to set the "key"

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Log.w("READ THIS!!!", gson.toJson(objj));  // check your Log for warning "READ THIS!!!", this should be printed out:
        // {"contacts":[{"data":"some data","email":"some mail","one":"one?","cash":100},{"data":"some data1","email":"some mail1","one":"2?","cash":100},{"data":"some data2","email":"some mail2","one":"3?","cash":100}]}
```

EDIT2: This is how you should try to make your code look like (in comparisson to the example you provided):

```
        String donations = null;
        ContactsObject objj = new ContactsObject();
        ArrayList<myDonations> donationList = new ArrayList<myDonations>();

        try
        {
            donationList = new DonationManager().getList();  // or however you get the array list
            objj.setListContacts(donationList);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            donations = gson.toJson(objj);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but where I need to add this key? in my contact class in web service?
I think using:
public String toString()
{
return "Contact [email=" + email + ", one=" + one + ", data=" + data + ", cash=" + cash + "]";
}
That was my key, but there isn't in json response....

Comment: Can you put a part of the code where you use this `contacts` class? Just to check how you create json object...

Comment: Sure, you can see my web service there:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443247/java-web-service-mysql-with-parameter
In this case the class name is donation but is the same project

Comment: ("email")
("text1")
("text2")
("coin")

In this case was email-one-data-cash,  I change only the name...

Comment: Thanks for your help miselking, I don't understand one thing, where I need to create ContactsObject Class? In web service for create new json with that key?
And then you speak of MainActivity but where I put thist:
objj.setListContacts(moreContacts);  // doing this to set the "key"

        Gson gson = new Gson();
in DonationService on web service for create new json after htt request?

Comment: Yes, the ContactsObject (or however you name it) class goes in web service project to create new json with that key, and you call the code you mentioned in the DonationService. That way, you will create a new json with a key. In comparison to the example of the web service you gave, it should look similar to this (still depends on your project's implementation):

 `donationList = new DonationManager().getList();
 objj.setListContacts(donationList);
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 donations = gson.toJson(objj);`

Comment: Thank you so much, soved!
Now my json is like that:
{"myDonations":[
{"email":"prova","one":"test","data":"2015-02-10 00:00:00.0","cash":100},
{"email":"prova","one":"provadue","data":"2015-02-11 23:41:32.0","cash":15}
]
Now I can try to parse that json in jsonarray and put in listview ^^

Comment: one last thing if I may, in your opinion is the best choice to use: ContactList = new ArrayList <HashMap <String, String >> ();
to take the json data and populate listview?

Comment: Probably, yes... I worked on a project a while ago, and if I remember correctly, I used `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();` to populate the listview...
Glad I could help... :)